# How to create a random race track for SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, random, sprite-kit

I want to create a racing game with a racetrack that gets generated randomly.

Here is a sketch of how I want it to be:

[Racetrack sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeaEl.jpg)

I want the racetrack to be a physics body. While the racetrack moves to the left side of the screen it changes it gets generated on the right screen but with random directions(curves) like displayed in the sketch. 
If the car at some point touches the edge of the road the game ends.

The only thing I need help with right now is how to generate the road as described above.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the racetrack a physics body, the car will be a physics body too I suppose, moving in a physics body. It sounds a bit counter-intuitive to how Spritekit is designed. You could consider making the racetrack sides (upper curve and lower curve) edges. Then have the car move there in the middle, if it touches you should get a collision.

I did something similar recently (did a Dune!-like ball jumping game on a curvy landscape) and approached so that you randomise a set of y-coordinates in your given range, e.g. something like

```
    let yPointRandomizer = GKGaussianDistribution(lowestValue: -500, highestValue: -200)
    var highGroundPositions = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPointRandomizer.nextInt())]
    for i in 1...50 {
        highGroundPositions.append(CGPoint(x: (i * 400) + 200, y: yPointRandomizer.nextInt()))
    }
```

What this gives you is are the coordinates that the curve goes to. Then to draw the shape and get an edge:

```
let splineShapeNode = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &highGroundPositions,
                                      count: highGroundPositions.count)
splineShapeNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: splineShapeNode.path!)
```

Note that the code above creates the first at x=0 and moves to the right, so adjust per your needs. Hope this help you to get started.

Comment: In which function do I have to put those two parts of the code? @GOR

Comment: Well, the first part is the y-coordinates for the landscape and the second part is the Node and its physics body. Really depends on your project structure. My suggestion would be to take a look here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit and try out something even simpler first perhaps to learn the framework. Even something like just creating ball shapes and physics for them and running just to get comfortable with how SpriteKit works.

Comment: Do you know how to move the move the SKShapeNode to the left?